# Stopping rotation by hovering the child

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to hover the menu so I can stop the rotation, which is circle, parent of menu, but i don't know how to make it work. I am using animation to animate the circle as parent so the child will all follow the rotation. and I use spin so the child won't be wrongly spinned.

I have this

```
<div id="circle"
  style="margin-left:430px;margin-top:60px;width:450px;height:450px;
  border-radius:15%;position:absolute;z-index:1;
  -webkit-animation: spin 6s linear infinite reverse;">
      <a href="#" class="menu"
      style="margin-left:15px;margin-top:20px;background-color:#91c8e5;">
        <p>Java</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="menu"
      style="margin-left:285px;margin-top:20px;background-color:#c3f797;">
        <p>C++</p>
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="menu"
      style="margin-left:15px;margin-top:290px; background-color:#a09cea;">
        <p>Python</p>   
      </a>
      <a href="#" class="menu"
      style="margin-left:285px;margin-top:290px; background-color:#fff368;">
        <p>PHP</p>  
      </a>
  </div>
```

and this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*main*/
    $("#logo").click(function(){
        $(".menu").animate({
            opacity: '1',   
        });
    });
    $(".menu").hover(function(){
        $("#circle").stop(true);
    });
    $("#logo").dblclick(function(){
        $(".menu").animate({
            opacity: '0'
        });
    });

    /*
    login
    $("#create").click(function(){
        $(".left").animate({
            "margin-left": '-=200px'
        });

        $(".right").animate({
            opacity: '1'
        });
    });
    */  
});
```

This part seems not working

```
$(".menu").hover(function(){
        $("#circle").stop(true);
    });
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Where is animation css?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nqs285bo/